# How do i use named routes in an Rails engine's specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rails-engines

I have a Rails Engine with the engine.rb defined:

```
module Keywords
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Keywords
end
```

I have some routes defined:

```
Keywords::Engine.routes.draw do
  resources :keyword_groups,  only: [:new] 
end
```

Now, everything works great inside my dummy app.  i can use the variable `keywords.new_keyword_group_path` to get a url to my path.

However, when i try to do the same in my rspec tests using capybara, it fails!  i tried to add the following line to my spec_helper.rb as suggested:

```
config.include Keywords::Engine.routes.url_helpers
```

But, when i try to use the following line in my tests:

```
visit keywords.new_keyword_group_path
```

I get the following error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `keywords' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x00000108833390>
```

If i instead try to leave off the "keywords" prefix, and do:

```
visit new_keyword_group_path
```

i get this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/keyword_groups/new"
```

which makes sense as the path should be "/keywords/keyword_groups/new".

How can i get the included url helpers to use the correct namespace prefix?

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution for this based on the Spree gem.  creating a helper method for the prefix to grab the path from the engines routes like so:

```
def keywords
  Keywords::Engine.routes.url_helpers
end
```

then `keywords.new_keyword_path` works like a charm